# Trying to write my own reverse function

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, reverse

I am trying to write my own reverse algorithm that reverses the order of a sequence of elements. I am only using a 'first' and 'limit' and thats all the function will have as parameters. Is it possible to write a function that reverses the order of a sequence of elements where the first is the last and second is second to last.. etc. I am trying not to use a temporary vector to store the elements. Is this possible? Let me know if anything was unclear in my question.
 Thank you!
I am using c++11 and this is what i have so far.. not much. I don't really know what logic to use if i dont want to use a temporary vector.

```
template<typename Iter>
void reverse(Iter first, Iter last)
{

}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << reverse(vector.begin(),vector.end());
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and which programming language are we talking about?

Comment: I have added it to the question up at the top, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Use a temporary variable in the function initialised to 0. Swap the first last iterator elements and then add 1 and subtract 1 position from the first and last so as to point to second and second last elements and continue the swap until left<right. And check if the vector has odd elements and left pointer is equal to right then stop.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you'd do this manually. Place five playing cards on a table:

```
A K Q J 10
```

Now, you want to reverse the order, in-place. You want the 10 at the beginning, and the Ace at the end. So swap them:

```
10 K Q J A
```

Now swap the King and the Jack:

```
10 J Q K A
```

And your list is reversed!

That general algorithm will work for lists of any size. I'll leave the coding to you.

A little hint about solving these types of problems: don't try to solve it at the computer. Instead, build a physical model (like the playing cards), and think about how you would solve the problem without the computer. You'll be surprised how often this works, and the more often you do it, the better you become at it.

Algorithm design isn't about coding. Algorithm design is about coming up with the steps to solve a problem. After you have an approach, *then* you write code to implement the solution.

Comment: That's the thing, am trying to get it so it would work for any size and im not quite sure it would work that way, the way that i would use swap. I know what you're saying in the sense of how to do it for a fixed vector size but not if it would vary

Comment: Yes, you can write a general algorithm that works for any size.

Answer (score -1):

Using [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) should easily allow you to do this.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least leave a comment why.